# How to get rid of a permanent margin on the left side of each page, in a twoside document?

Tags: margins, thesis

I have got a problem with a coma-script book document (my master-thesis). I like to have a normal twoside document, with normal margins and a BCOR, but whatever I do there is this small margin on the left side of each page.

I got the template for latex from someone else, so I do not know every detail of why and what changes are made to it. But I already went through most of them and still can not find the sorce of the margin.

Does someone have an idea where it might come from or how to get rid of it?

Thank you a lot!

Minimal working example:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,idxtotoc,headsepline,footsepline,footexclude,prak,BCOR5mm,DIV12, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1.25in,left=1in,right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Every page shows a margin on the left side, odd and even pages. Where does it come from and how to get rid of it?]

Solution: There was a additional binding correction hidden in the titlepage chapter (where I did not search for layout options..)

```
\def\bcorcor{0.15cm} \addtolength{\hoffset}{\bcorcor}
```

Comment: when you use geometry, BCOR and DIV will have no effect. Set the BCOR with the option of geometry. But beside this, your settings seems ok, and whatever you are seeing (I don't) is probably a viewer problem.

Comment: Hey Ulrike, it is hard to see what I mean, but there is a margin on the very left of each page, seperated with a line from top to bottom (displayed by package showframe) and everything is shiftet to the right.

Comment: I don't see it. How do you compile? Is your tex system up-to-date? Which viewer do you use? Do you have the problem too if you remove the package showframe and use the showframe option of geometry instead?

Comment: Note, there is a PDF origin which defaults to about 2pt above and to the right of the lower left corner of the page, but using geometry should fix that.  Try putting a4paper as a geometry argument.

Comment: I compile with pdflatex. And yes it is still there but - not displayed - from showframe of geometry package.

a4paper to geometry didn't do anything unfortunately. 

I would guess that the mistake is caused somewhere in another package, option or command, but as there are a lot of them I did not want to include them all.. but maybe someone has an idea where this might come from.

Comment: I found the origin of the problem!!  \def\bcorcor{0.15cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{\bcorcor}, was hidden in the "titlepage" chapter where I never looked for layout options and suff. Thanks to everyone!